# SwiftUI PageTabViewStyle does not ignore safe area

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am attempting to implement a PageTabViewStyle inside a NavigationView so that I can swipe between two different lists but the TabView does not ignore the safe area despite having `.ignoresSafeArea()`.

Code

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selectedPage = 0
    private var pages = [0, 1]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
                FirstList()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(0)
                
                SecondList()
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Picker("", selection: $selectedPage) {
                        ForEach(pages, id: \.self) {
                            Text(String($0))
                        }
                    }
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("0")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("1")
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

How do I set it such that the list view would fill the navigationBar like the image below:

[image]

Note that adding a background color is not preferred as I would like to maintain the navigationBar tint effect when the list view is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `List` has its own background. You can either set `listStyle` to .plain or manually set the color of List background e.g. onAppear.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedPage = 0
    private var pages = [0, 1]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
                FirstList()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(0)
                
                SecondList()
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear {
                // UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.clear) // solution2
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Picker("", selection: $selectedPage) {
                        ForEach(pages, id: \.self) {
                            Text(String($0))
                        }
                    }
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("0")
        }
        .listStyle(.plain) //solution1
    }
}

struct SecondList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("1")
        }
        .listStyle(.plain) //solution1
    }
}
```